# Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` - Rails 4.2.0 with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Recently I pulled one of my repos from Git. After launching the server, I am receiving the the following: **Missing secret_token and secret_key_base**.
This may be happening because I've included the secrets.yml in my .gitignore.

My current setup

- Ubuntu 14.04
- ruby 2.2.0p0
- rails 4.2.0
- rvm 1.26.11
- local server (not remote)
- development environment

Many online resources state that I must gen a new key using `rake secret` and add it to the secrets.yml. Placing the key inside the secrets.yml and restarting the rails server does not work.

---

> **Edited: Added contents of secrets.yml below. -04/30/15 9:04 AM EST**

```
development:
    secret_key_base: LONG KEY HERE

test:
  secret_key_base: LONG KEY HERE

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Please know this is set as a development environment on a local server in my place of residence (not Heroku).

---

Other resources state I need to add an entry inside my `secret_token.rb` but this file does not exist in my project.

The only way my application will run is if I were to create a `secret_token.rb` file and add either one of the following inside of it:

```
MyApp::Application.config.secret_token = if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
  ('x' * 30) # meets minimum requirement of 30 chars long
else
  ENV['SECRET_TOKEN-']
end
```

or

```
MyApp::Application.config.secret_token = 'the secret key'
```

Why is this file required when the Rails docs states to remove it?

[3.3 config/secrets.yml](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml)

The secret_token.rb is not required in order to run for new generated projects, only the ones from my Git repo.

Please advise on why my application needs secret_token.rb though the Rails docs state otherwise or my application will not run without it.

> **Edited: -04/30/15 9:27 AM EST**

Another strange behavior is I can rename `secrets.yml` while the `secret_token.rb` remains in place and the application will still run.

I attempted to rename the `secret_token.rb`, added `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>` to development and I'm still experiencing the Missing secret_token issue.

> **Edited: Added git repo below. -05/08/15 2:50 AM EST**

git repo: https://github.com/captain-awesome/blog_mac

Something strange is if I were to modify any one of the 32 characters, save the secret_token.rb, reload the server...my app will run. Is the 32 character string in the secret_token.rb something I can make-up on my own? If so, what is the real purpose for rake secret?

Comment: So first of all, `('x' * 30)`, no no no.  You can generate a secret token by running `rake secret` in your app, that's the right way to generate a secret token. But this doesn't answer the bulk of your question, so I'll just leave it as a comment here. You might also want to look up the purpose of the secret token, so you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Are you launching your server locally in development or in some other environment (for instance, on Heroku in production)?  Because if you are running on Heroku, then you'll need to remove `secrets.yml` from your `.gitignore` so that Heroku can figure out what the secret key is.  The safe way of handling this is to store your secret key as an environment variable on Heroku and have your `secrets.yml` point to it (see below).

If you are running locally, you should be able to delete your `secret_token.rb` as long as you have your `secret_key_base` set for every environment inside your `secrets.yml` file.  You didn't post what yours looks like, but it should look something like this:

```
development:
 secret_key_base: somerandomkey
test:
 secret_key_base: somerandomkey
staging:
 secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
production:
 secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Hi Hannah, thanks for your response. I've added the contents for the secrets.yml and stated my staging as being development in my post.

Answer (score 3):

**As of Rails 4.1, there is a [new way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml) to store secrets.**

In Rails 4.1+, **you need `config/secrets.yml` – do not delete it!** I can see in your GitHub repo, you are using Rails 4.2 and that this file is missing. This is why you see that error. (*Note: if you still have a  secret_token.rb file, remove it. Rails 4.1+ no longer uses it*).

I recommend using [dotenv rails](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

Add and commit *config/secrets.yml:*

```
default: &default
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

staging:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Whenever you launch rails, you need to make sure you set the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` system *environement variable*. With the above YAML file, you need to ensure this environment variable is set on whatever machine that starts your Rails app in whatever environment. The key point is, this *how* this variable is set may vary depending on where/what your machine is.

On your **local machine** (at home), create a file called `.env` with a secret:

```
echo SECRET_KEY_BASE=`rake secret` > .env
rails server
```

You only need to create this file *once*. When rails starts, dotenv will read this `.env` file, and set the environement variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` appropriately. Do not commit this file – in fact, I recommend adding it to your `.gitignore`.

Later, when you deploy to a **remove server** (a production/deployment server), things will be different. You may need to use SSH to set the environment variable. On Heroku, you can sign in to your [app's dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) and set an environment value (or use `config:set` in [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)).

**Edit:** *Note I didn't invent this. This is the approach used by [Suspenders](https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders).*

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to generate your token and keybase is:

```
bundle exec rake secret
```

Now you will get a long string like:

> ddf4a6d37a956089984c8fe6160a6e3c18e48a448a07a50e4ab10a4edd6d3597f13ad9b6e0af4f5723f1ef52bfd2ffa78ab5b815d2bb8b15f14f48e7e307baad

copy same string which you got on your Terminal/CMD

Now run this command:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=ddf4a6d37a956089984c8fe6160a6e3c18e48a448a07a50e4ab10a4edd6d3597f13ad9b6e0af4f5723f1ef52bfd2ffa78ab5b815d2bb8b15f14f48e7e307baad

rails s -e production
```

Whenever you want to change your secret key follow above steps. Do not write it in file for security reasons.